# iOS Drop down menu from right bar button don't get selected

Tags: ios, uitableview, drop-down-menu, uinavigationbar, uigesturerecognizer

I used [NIDropDown](https://github.com/BijeshNair/NIDropDown) example and I want to create little menu that would drop down from right navigation bar when tapped. I saw other examples too but I don't want to fill whole controller it's enough for me when I just fill space below button and it's really easy with example from that component. The problem is that I can't select any rows in shown table except just first one. I guess it's because rest of table is outside navigation bar, am I right? How can I fix it? Can I extend somehow area of gesture recognizer? Or should I add new recognizer to table?

In my controller I have these lines of code for creating right bar button and showing drop down list:

```
- (void)setRightBarButtonItem
{
    UIButton *rightButton = [NavigationBarHelper getRightBarButtonItemForMenu];
    [rightButton addTarget:self action:@selector(rightBarButtonTapped:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchDown];
    self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithCustomView:rightButton];
}

- (void)rightBarButtonTapped:(id)sender
{
    MAAppDelegate* appDelegate = (MAAppDelegate*)[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];
    NSArray *menuItems = [appDelegate menuItems];
    NSArray *arrayOfNames = [menuItems valueForKey:@"text"];
    if(dropDown == nil) {
        CGFloat f = 320;
        dropDown = [[NIDropDown alloc]showDropDown:sender :&f :arrayOfNames :nil :@"down"];
        dropDown.delegate = nil;
        [_tableView setUserInteractionEnabled:NO];
    }
    else {
        [dropDown hideDropDown:sender];
        dropDown = nil;
        [_tableView setUserInteractionEnabled:YES];
    }
}
```

And here is `showDropDown` method:

```
- (id)showDropDown:(UIButton *)b:(CGFloat *)height:(NSArray *)arr:(NSArray *)imgArr:(NSString *)direction {
    btnSender = b;
    animationDirection = direction;
    self.table = (UITableView *)[super init];
    if (self) {
        // Initialization code
        CGRect btn = b.frame;
        self.list = [NSArray arrayWithArray:arr];
        self.imageList = [NSArray arrayWithArray:imgArr];
        if ([direction isEqualToString:@"up"]) {
            self.frame = CGRectMake(btn.origin.x, btn.origin.y, btn.size.width, 0);
            self.layer.shadowOffset = CGSizeMake(-5, -5);
        }else if ([direction isEqualToString:@"down"]) {
            self.frame = CGRectMake(btn.origin.x, btn.origin.y+btn.size.height, btn.size.width, 0);
            self.layer.shadowOffset = CGSizeMake(-5, 5);
        }

        self.layer.masksToBounds = NO;
        self.layer.shadowRadius = 5;
        self.layer.shadowOpacity = 0.5;

        table = [[UITableView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 140, 0)]; //btn.size.width
        table.delegate = self;
        table.dataSource = self;
        table.backgroundColor = kDarkGreen;
        table.separatorStyle = UITableViewCellSeparatorStyleSingleLine;
        table.separatorColor = [UIColor grayColor];

        [UIView beginAnimations:nil context:nil];
        [UIView setAnimationDuration:0.5];
        if ([direction isEqualToString:@"up"]) {
            self.frame = CGRectMake(btn.origin.x, btn.origin.y-*height, btn.size.width, *height);
        } else if([direction isEqualToString:@"down"]) {
            self.frame = CGRectMake(btn.origin.x, btn.origin.y+btn.size.height, 140, *height); //btn.size.width
        }
        table.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, 140, *height); //btn.size.width
        [UIView commitAnimations];
        [b.superview addSubview:self];
        [self addSubview:table];
    }
    return self;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

iOS will let you have a view which draws outside of its parent view's bounds--assuming you allow it with `masksToBounds = NO`.  Unfortunately, anything drawn outside of the view's bounds will not pick up touches appropriately.

Comment: And is there some trick how can I detect it? Or I must use another solution for this? The weird thing is that when I set `masksToBounds` to `YES` I still have table visible outside navigation bar.

Comment: if you set self.masksToBounds = NO, then all subviews will be masked as well.  (The problem could be coming from your superview as well).